# ¿Cómo imprimo este módulo en pantalla?

Tags: java, modular

```
import java.io.*;

public class Banco
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
        BufferedReader Input=new BufferedReader (reader); 

        CuentaBancaria c1 = new CuentaBancaria ();
        CuentaBancaria c2 = new CuentaBancaria ("44", 23456, 1);
    }

    public static class CuentaBancaria
    { 
        private String nif;
        private float valor;
        private long nCuenta;

        public CuentaBancaria () 
        {
            nif = " ";
            valor = 0.0F;
            nCuenta = 1;
        } //Método Constructor (Por Defecto)

        public CuentaBancaria (String _ident, long _cident, float v)
        {
            nif = _ident;
            valor = v;
            nCuenta = _cident;
        }//Metodo Constructor (Parametrizado)

        public String MostrarDatos () //Quiero imprimir a eso, como en c++
        {
            System.out.println("NIF del Titular de la cuenta: " + nif);
            System.out.println("Número de cuenta: " + nCuenta);
        }
    }

}
```

Hola, estoy aprendiendo la programación modular en Java. Quiero aprender cómo hacer para llamar a una función e imprimir en pantalla los *out* que hay dentro de sí (como en C++), cosa que hago un *cout* de la función y la imprimo (cuando se puede, claro). Si hay algo malo dímelo porfa que estoy empezando con Java. Gracias.

Comment: Solamente manda a llamar el método **MostrarDatos()** en tu main con `c1.MostrarDatos();` y `c2.MostrarDatos();`, y en el método MostrarDatos() solo cambia el retorno de String a void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé cómo funciona exactamente en C++, pero en Java para hacer lo que pides simplemente tienes que crear un objeto de la clase (en tu caso `c1` y `c2`) y después llamar en cada uno al respectivo método que imprime. Se realizaría del siguiente modo:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
    BufferedReader Input=new BufferedReader (reader); 

    CuentaBancaria c1 = new CuentaBancaria ();
    CuentaBancaria c2 = new CuentaBancaria ("44", 23456, 1);

    c1.MostrarDatos();
    c2.MostrarDatos();
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.